# How do I make reverse and forward commands?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

So I have a app that searches for anime quotes, it presents users with list of quotes in the database and if they mentioned any criteria related it refines the list until user selects one of the quote card. It then presents them with a list of quotes from that anime and presents them with a detailed view. My dilemma is how do I make a feature that allows users to go back and forth incase they want to see the previous results. For an app like this I think it will benefits users to browser through cards.

So For Example:

-> users searched for "life lesson" Quotes ::: Bixby (View 1) Output a list of anime that fits the criteria 
-> users ask for a quote that one of the character has said when Bixby (View 2) showed them quotes from the anime card they selected ::: Bixby (View 3) shows the quote they selected (View 2) in detail view. 
-> now user wants to go back the criteria they first searched (View 1) because they might forgot the criteria they mentioned (lets assume due to some distraction).

So, how do I make bixby present the original view? and incase users after coming back to original view might want to go to list of quotes bixby pulled of for some reference, how do I make bixby go back to that (View 2)

Let me know if you want to clear some details that you found confusing. Thanks

PS: I think it just might be easier if we had a feature that helps us go back and forth with Session Requests like the back arrow in the Bixby Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

How about presenting the criteria to the user and let them verify/add/delete any existing filters? That would technically have the same result as going back to make any changes.

Comment: That would be a nice idea, I can also randomize and short-list criteria such that user don’t get feeling of same old listsZ thanks